# Move cue point to previous beat in Traktor

Tags: software, beats, dj, traktor

I have a cue point in Traktor that I set while the track was playing and I missed the beginning of the chorus by one beat. Is there a way to snap the cue point backward one beat without having to delete the current cue point and set a new one?

Answer (score 1):

If your cue is exactly one beat after the desired cue point then just create a one beat loop and move the loop one beat back. This will set you exactly one beat back.

Comment: I think Keyslinger may have meant, without interrupting (or looping) play.